# Ren'Py will not install python module turtle

Tags: python, pip, renpy

I am trying to install python module turtle to my Ren'Py game. However, it will not install even if I clean the cache and download a fresh version of turtle:

```
pip install --target game/python-packages turtle

Collecting turtle
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/f0/21a42e9e424d24bdd0e509d5ed3c7dfb8f47d962d9c044dba903b0b4a26f/turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/np/9134zq452dj8pt6435_dqb6h0000gn/T/pip-install-lzh_pa9s/turtle/setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/np/9134zq452dj8pt6435_dqb6h0000gn/T/pip-install-lzh_pa9s/turtle/
```

Comment: The [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) module has been part of the Python standard library for *many* years. Are you sure you need to install anything at all?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `except ValueError, ve:` is Python2-syntax and you're installing the module with Python3. The module was not updated since 2009, it's certainly Python2-only.

The actual module `turtle` is a part of the standard library, you don't need to install it, it must always be available.

Comment: Well, I think Ren'Py uses a special version of python. It returns [this error](http://h2database.com/p.html#574be833a2f9130827046e567cea8ff3)when I try to import it like this:                                                                                          `label start:
    init python:
        import turtle`